# How to add case expression in SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I tried following query to get incoming payment details of customers. What is the wrong in this case statement? What i needed here is display payment type if it has amount.

```
select convert(varchar,a.DocDate,110) as DocDate,
       a.CardCode,
       a.CardName,
       d.SlpName,
       e.CheckNum,
       (case when a.CashSum >= 0 then "Cash Payment" when a.CreditSum >= 0 then "Credit Card Payment" when a.CheckSum >= 0 then "Cheque Payment" else "Bank Transfer" end) as 'Payment type',
       (ISNULL(a.CashSum,0) + ISNULL(a.CreditSum,0) + ISNULL(a.CheckSum,0) + ISNULL(a.TrsfrSum,0)) as DocTotal 
from ORCT a
left join RCT2 b on b.DocNum=a.DocNum
Left Join OINV c on c.DocNum = b.DocEntry
Left join OSLP d on d.SlpCode = c.SlpCode
left join RCT1 e on e.DocNum = a.DocEntry
```

It gives following error
[image]

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: You tell us whats wrong? Either you're getting an error? Or unexpected results? If an error please post it. In the case of unexpected results please post sample data, actual results and expected results.

Comment: I think you might want `>0` instead of `>=0`. Your syntax seems fine to me, but without knowing if you get an error or simply results that are different then expected, it's kind of a shot in the dark.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server literal strings are enclosed in single quotes `'`, not double quotes `"`.

The column (object) names, on the other hand, are enclosed in brackets `[Payment type]`, or double quotes  `"Payment type"`.

So, your query should look like:

```
case 
    when a.CashSum >= 0 then 'Cash Payment' 
    when a.CreditSum >= 0 then 'Credit Card Payment'
    when a.CheckSum >= 0 then 'Cheque Payment'
    else 'Bank Transfer' 
end as [Payment type]
```

Comment: Aliases can either be enclosed in brackets or in quotes, but good point I somehow missed on the string literals.

Comment: oh.Thank you so much.Worked

Comment: @Kith Then please mark the appropriate responses as answers if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the double quotes to single quote in the  following case expression in the `THEN` block:

```
(case when a.CashSum >= 0 then "Cash Payment" when a.CreditSum >= 0 then "Credit Card Payment" when a.CheckSum >= 0 then "Cheque Payment" else "Bank Transfer" end) as 'Payment type',
```

to

```
(case when a.CashSum >= 0 then 'Cash Payment' when a.CreditSum >= 0 then 'Credit Card Payment' when a.CheckSum >= 0 then 'Cheque Payment' else 'Bank Transfer' end) as 'Payment type',
```

Example with db<>fiddle demo:

Receiving error when using [dobule quotes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c809ac92335037d7af937185a06f7d36) in `THEN`

Working after changed to [single quotes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2cc17387ae41a94cbc683bf00565d796) in `THEN`